# cant display view in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

hi im new to android studio, i want to add a view inside a viewgroup, the viewgroup is displayed correctly but the view inside no. here is the code :

```
class Bookview extends ViewGroup
{
    public Bookview(Context context,int height)
    {
        super(context);

         height = 732;
         int heightx = height/2;


        this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height));
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#327dcf"));
 
      //view to add
        HorizontalScrollView myview = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        myview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,heightx));
        myview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dd42f5"));
        this.addView(myview);
      }  
  }
```

[image]

}

this is what i get in the layout inspector, the view is added but not displayed.
whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data inside HorizontalScrollView